# Basic Authentication

Tags: asp.net

I have one VS application named Dotnetpanel, which provides a lot of webservices.

I created another another VS application say TestModule in which I need to create the webservice client. But when I try to create a client and call the webservice in TestModule, an error occured"The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized." From one of articles I have read that

DotNetPanel API implemented as a set of SOAP Web Services.

Requirements:
WSE 3.0 or Basic Authentication
****Each API call should have user’s credentials provided****

Basic Authentication:
For interacting with DotNetPanel API you should use Basic Authentication. DotNetPanel recognizes “Authorization” header with the user credentials provided in the following format: username:password.

So my question is I have a user credentials which can pass to the TestModule and after that how can I call the DotnetPanel webservices from the TestModule with Basic Authentication.

Regards

Fenix

Comment: Do you get the error when you create the client or when you call it? Are you using add Web Services Reference to create the cient?

Comment: I got the error when I call it. Error is " The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized." Yes I created one client which contains a lot of webmethods. My requirement is to access one webmethod say GetDomains(). So while trying to access this method I got the above error. esMailServers esm = new esMailServers(); MailDomain[] md; int authResult = 1; // authResult=AuthenticateUser("username", "password", "127.0.0.1", true, "", ""); md=esm.GetDomains(6, true); } while accessing GetDomains error occurs –

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me that you have to send those credentials as a parameter to the web service.
Try to call the web service url to see its methods. When calling to the web service directly from the browser, you have to be able to see a list of methods, then search for the method you're trying to use and click on it. You'll see the SOAP request and response definitions. You can take a look at what parameters is the web service expecting. I think if it asks you for credentials, there has to be a couple of param for that there.

Hope it helps.